# How to create a helper rendering multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 7.1, what's the correct way to move the following snippet into a helper method?

```
<%= button_tag type: "submit", class: "a" do %>
  <span class="b">SAVE</span>
  <%= svg "check-circle-solid" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def svg(name)
    file = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "#{name}.svg")
    File.read(file).html_safe
  end

  def primary_button(text:, icon:)
    button_tag type: "a" do
      content_tag("span", text, class: "b")
      svg(icon)
    end
  end
end
```

But the `span` isn't rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button_tag` is just a thin wrapper around [`content_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) which when called with a block uses [`capture`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) to create a string buffer with the contents of the tag.

In the ERB example this works because plain text is output straight to the buffer and `<%= ... %>` ERB tags also output to the buffer. This buffer plus the outer tags are the return value of `content_tag`.

```
<%= button_tag type: "submit", class: "a" do %>
  <span class="b">SAVE</span> <-- raw text
  <%= svg "check-circle-solid" %> <-- the result of the expression is output
<% end %>
```

However in a normal Ruby method the result of an expression is not automatically printed to the buffer:

```
  def primary_button(text:, icon:)
    button_tag type: "a" do
      content_tag("span", text, class: "b") # this does absolutely nothing
      svg(icon)
    end
  end
```

Only the return value of the block is output which is the last expression.

One way to solve this is to use [`concat`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) to output to the string buffer:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def primary_button(text:, icon:)
    button_tag type: "a" do
      concat(content_tag("span", text, class: "b"))
      concat(svg(icon))
    end
  end
end
```

You can further clean this up with [the more modern syntax](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/new-syntax-for-tag-helpers-in-rails-5-1) for the tag helpers:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def primary_button(text:, icon:)
    tag.a do
      concat(tag.span(text, class: "b"))
      concat(svg(icon))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @max for the reply. I ended up using your latest suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, the last line of a block is what is returned, so in your example, the return of the `button_tag` block is the `svg(icon)` line.

to get the helper to render out both, you'll need to combine them:

```rb
def primary_button(text:, icon:)
  button_tag type: "a" do
    content_tag("span", text, class: "b") + svg(icon)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use the [`concat`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) TextHelper e.g. `content_tag("span", text, class: "b").concat(svg(icon))` or `concat(content_tag("span", text, class: "b")); concat(svg(icon))` but for this simple case Buffer `+` works just as well (and essentially does the same thing)

Comment: Thanks @unixmonkey, I like the cleanness of using `+` over `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

As Unixmonkey mentioned in Ruby result of last line is a return value

I suggest to use [`safe_join`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join). You can pass few elements using array with this method

Also `tag` helper I believe is more readable in the code than `content_tag`

```rb
def primary_button(text:, icon:)
  button_tag type: "a" do
    safe_join([tag.span(text, class: "b"), svg(icon)])
  end
end
```

BTW there is convenient [inline_svg](https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg) gem to work with SVG

Comment: I'm aware of the inline_svg gem. However, I'd rather write a few lines of code than add a dependency.