# SVG not displayed when using an helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, assets

Any ideas why in Rails 7.1, the following code

```
 <%= button_tag type: "submit", class: "inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 rounded-md bg-black px-3.5 py-2.5 w-full sm:w-min text-sm font-semibold text-zinc-200 hover:text-white focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-black" do %>
  <span class="first-letter:capitalize"><%=t ("save") %></span>
  <svg class="h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" fill="currentColor">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.25 12c0-5.385 4.365-9.75 9.75-9.75s9.75 4.365 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75 9.75S2.25 17.385 2.25 12zm13.36-1.814a.75.75 0 10-1.22-.872l-3.236 4.53L9.53 12.22a.75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06l2.25 2.25a.75.75 0 001.14-.094l3.75-5.25z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
<% end %>
```

renders (as expected) [image]

While, if I try to render the same SVG with an helper method

```
 <%= button_tag type: "submit", class: "inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 rounded-md bg-black px-3.5 py-2.5 w-full sm:w-min text-sm font-semibold text-zinc-200 hover:text-white focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-black" do %>
  <span class="first-letter:capitalize"><%=t ("save") %></span>
  <%= svg "check-circle-solid" %>
<% end %>
```

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def svg(name)
    file = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "#{name}.svg")
    File.read(file).html_safe
  end
end
```

it renders [image]

Even if the inspected code looks like

[image]

I tried a few browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) but the issue persists.

Comment: I would ensure that your `tailwind.config.js` file has `'./app/assets/images/*.svg',` included in the `content` array and tailwind is currently watching for changes with `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch`. My suspicion is that the `h-6` and `w-6` classes aren't being applied as you expect them to be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a helper rendering multiple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061281/how-to-create-a-helper-rendering-multiple-methods)

Comment: Hi @herrstrietzel, that doesn't seem to be the cause. Thanks anyway for taking the time to give me your suggestion.

Comment: @Ted, thanks for the reply. Updating `tailwind.config.js` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar method to render svg, It takes path of the svg stored in the assets folder...

```
## can be used as embedded_svg("kiwi.svg")
def embedded_svg filename, options={}
   file = File.read(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'svgs', filename))
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse file
   svg = doc.at_css 'svg'
   if options[:class].present?
     svg['class'] = options[:class]
   end
   doc.to_html.html_safe
 end
```